# Hibernate and Postgres : function st_buffer(bytea, numeric) is not unique

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-5.x

I'm working with `Hibernate 5.1.0` in a Java application. I'm connecting both to a `Postgres 9.5` with `Postgis` extensions and `Oracle` databases. 
I need to find all the geometries in my database that intersect with a given geometry to which I apply a **buffer**, such as :

```
Query query = session
            .createQuery("select b from Block b where intersects(b.geom, buffer(:geometry, " + bufferDistance + ")) = "
                    + UtilsHelper.getTrueBooleanValue(em));
query.setParameter("geometry", geom);
List<Block> blocks = query.list();
```

That works in Oracle, but in Postgres I will get the error :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function st_buffer(bytea, numeric) is not unique
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 243
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
```

This makes sense, as it will not be able to choose between one of the following functions :

```
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer);
geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer_in_meters);
```

The `UtilsHelper.getTrueBooleanValue(em)` will just get the right boolean value depending on the entity manager, that is, 0/1 for Oracle and true/false for Postgres.

One obvious solution would be to drop one of the functions. Other than that, is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I won't claim to know much about Hibernate, but it seems that a simple fix is to [explicitly cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html) the bytea with `CAST(:geometry AS geometry)`, and modernize the rest query to add a "ST_" prefix, which is used with newer PostGIS versions.

More importantly, you should never write a query with the form:

```
SELECT b
FROM Block b
WHERE ST_Intersects(b.geom, ST_Buffer(CAST(:geometry AS geometry), :bufferDistance)) = TRUE;
```

Using a buffer to select a region is slower and imperfect than using a distance-based [ST_DWithin function](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to find the geometries that are within a distance. ST_DWithin can also use a spatial index, if available. And a boolean operator does not need to have the `= + UtilsHelper.getTrueBooleanValue(em)` part (i.e. `TRUE = TRUE` is `TRUE`). Just remove it.

Try to write a function that looks more like:

```
SELECT b
FROM Block b
WHERE ST_Dwithin(b.geom, CAST(:geometry AS geometry), :distance);
```

(using two parameters `:geometry` and `:distance`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mike T. I'm trying to make it work with that CAST. Anyway that will probably be good only for Postgres and not for Oracle. As commented, I need this to work with both DBs. Precisely that's why I'm relying on Hibernate to generate the actual query, be it with ST_Buffer or any ST_ prefix for Postgres or the SDO equivalent in Oracle.

Comment: @krause again I'm not familiar with Hibernate, but Oracle has [SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#i77653) which is equivalent to ST_DWithin mentioned above.